# Install updates

Tags: windows, windows-8, updates

I have set up my `Windows 8.1` to download updates and install them according to my request (not authomatically). Now I see message at the right conner of login windows `Importat updates are available. Go to PC setings to install them`. But I can't find any place where I could press button to install updates. Where is it? In `settings` I found `Update and recovery` section (picture below), but there is no any button to install downloaded updates.

[image]

Comment: If you've set it to be "not authomatically" - why is it stating "You're set to automatically download updates" in the screenshot?

Comment: You can hit "Check Now" and/or "view details".  You can also do CTRL+I go to Control Panel and search for `Windows Updates` located in exactly the same place as it was in `Windows 7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for updates and install them via the **Control Panel > Windows Updates**

You can simply reach this menu by searching for Windows Updates in the Moderm UI.
Or typing **control /name Microsoft.WindowsUpdate** on a 'Run' prompt.

Hope this helps.